# cannot open pdf file generated using dompdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, smarty, dompdf

i am trying to generate a pdf file from smarty template using dompdf:code is below:-

```
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($smarty->fetch(CURRENT_TEMPLATE.'/module/shopping_cart.html'));
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

a pdf file is generated,but when i try to open the pdf file a error message is displaying as below
"Acrobat cannot open the 'sample.pdf' because it is either not supported file type or because file has been damaged"
HTML page is diplaying correctly when i try to

```
echo $smarty->fetch(CURRENT_TEMPLATE.'/module/shopping_cart.html')
```

so please help me to solve this error...thanks in advance

Comment: To use stream() without corrupting the file,  see AntonAL suggestion below. It's the right answer to your question;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes this is an problem of dompdf. But I am able to overcome from this problem. I created a function for pdf creation. check below function:-

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $savein = 'uploads/policy_doc/';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("arial", "normal","12px");

    // the same call as in my previous example
    $canvas->page_text(540, 773, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                   $font, 6, array(0,0,0));

    $pdf = $dompdf->output();      // gets the PDF as a string

    file_put_contents($savein.str_replace("/","-",$filename), $pdf);    // save the pdf file on server
    unset($html);
    unset($dompdf); 

}
```

Note :- You need to get generated pdf as string then save it to pdf file.

**EDIT :- You may delete the below part from above function:-**

```
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("arial", "normal","12px");

    // the same call as in my previous example
    $canvas->page_text(540, 773, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                   $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
```

> this above code for handling multiple pages header.

Comment: thanks for the answer,but unfortunately it didn't works for me..why is this get_canvas(); used,please can you give some explanation of the code....thank you again

Comment: what error You are getting? You may omit get_canvas from Your code. this is using - if You have multiple page. then for each page header.

Comment: thank you very much.....it works :) no words for express my thanks..i am after it for past 2 days..a great relief now

Comment: You can use stream() but seen AntonAL suggestion below

Answer (score 27):

Use `ob_end_clean();` before calling `$dompdf->stream();`.

> This function discards the contents of the topmost output buffer and
> turns off this output buffering. If you want to further process the
> buffer's contents you have to call ob_get_contents() before
> ob_end_clean() as the buffer contents are discarded when
> ob_end_clean() is called.

[PHP manual ob_end_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

Comment: Should be chosen as answer.

Comment: its people like you that are the true hero's of stack overflow.

Answer (score 12):

I also got same error but when I use `ob_end_clean()` before `$dompdf->stream()` it worked for me.

Below is my code.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html); 
$dompdf->render();    
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$invnoabc = 'Bokkinglist.pdf';
ob_end_clean();
$dompdf->stream($invnoabc);
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

it works to me, at end my code looks like:

```
$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once('scripts/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $savein = '';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("arial", "normal","12px");

    /*// the same call as in my previous example
    $canvas->page_text(540, 773, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                   $font, 6, array(0,0,0));*/

    $pdf = $dompdf->output();      // gets the PDF as a string

    file_put_contents("arquivo.pdf",$pdf);  // save the pdf file on server

    unset($html);
    unset($dompdf); 

}

pdf_create($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

I having issue with my pdf created by dompdf
I open pdf file in notepad++ i found the below php error with dompdf

```
Message:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"
```

This happened due to old version of dompdf that could not be supported php 7 version 
after updating dompdf library the issue get resolved.

download latest dompdf library [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases)