# Convert web information to pdf information

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, pdf

I have an internal form that is web-based. Clients insert their information (Name and such) and sign using a signing pad (This is more than an image. It's the speed, pressure, ect of the signature).

I've got this working as PDF's, but the forms NOW need to be web based, and when the clients hit "save" the information they input is converted to PDF. This *must* be done server side.

Is there a way to program using HTML, JavaScript, or something else to do this?
Or is there a service that will do it automatically on the server?

*Nothing* can be saved locally.

(Short summary: information fields on local website, client inserts information to fields, signs using signing pad, and all information is sent to server and converted to PDF)

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but could PHP be used to do this? If so, how?
The reason i can't have it client side, is because we're trying to get the whole system to work on Ipads as well as desktop office computers

Answer (score 0):

There are library to build PDF in PHP, for instance fpdf.

In fact there are many libraries out there which allow you to build pdf, you just have to learn their respective API a little.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). It's the PHP library to generate PDFs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I used [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), it's easy to download and the site contains useful tutorials. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

use **dompdf**. check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676160/cannot-open-pdf-file-generated-using-dompdf/20676284#20676284)
From here check my answer on this question. You can download **dompdf** from [here](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/list)