# DOMPDF, able to create pdf doc but the pdf itself failed to load

Tags: php, pdf

Hi I'm trying to use php to covert html to pdf. The code is able to run and I able to run it and download a pdf file but when I open the pdf file it gives me this error

[image]

This is the code I have to run the php

```
   <?
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");



 ?>
```

I have a feeling that I'm loading the html wrong so the contents of the pdf is actually messing up, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   <?
^^^---- these spaces will corrupt the PDF
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

If you really do have those 3 spaces before your PHP opening tag, they will become part of the PDF file and corrupt it. Load up your "bad" pdf, do a file->save, and opening the file in a text/hex editor (**NOT** a pdf reader) and see what you're getting. Any PHP errors/warnings or other output before the actual PDF data will cause the PDF readers to see it as corrupted.

Answer (score 9):

Use `ob_end_clean();` before calling `$dompdf->stream();`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44318219/11272475

Answer (score 0):

### > Open it in a text editor (notepad++)

I had the same problem. 
I read something about opening the downloaded with a text editor. 
I did this and found that there was some javascript automatically included in the file which corrupted it.

I removed the lines that generated the javascript and this fixed it for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the browser was not able to display the pdf file ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zlJe.png)). After researching a lot over here and Google and a lot of test I've been able to make it work with this line:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($html));
```

Hope it works for you, too.

Answer (score -2):

DOMPDF requires you to set a default_timezone for your php app. it cannot rely on system's timezone settings

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same issue "pdf document is damaged".

Finally I find the solution.

First open pdf in text editor like(gedit) then I seen some additional style(css).After that i find that and comment it.now again download pdf and its work fine.

```
<style>
#certificatrediv > div{margin:0 auto !important;}
</style>
<h2>Test PDF</h2>
```

Answer (score -2):

This can happen as well when we have php warnings when generating the pdf document.

Setting error_reporting(0) on specific php file generating the pdf file is a remedy. Fixing the warning or having conditions to handle it is an even better solution

Answer (score -2):

It has to do with your php and xampp version. changed to xampp version 3.2.1 (php version 5.2) and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

the best solution i found so far is to open the pdf with some text editor , then you can see the error causing the file not being able to open, and you can fix it then, and one of the main raisons that may cause the error is the path to the html template

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).